# Correlation of $aX + bY$ and $cX + dY$ for independent normal RV

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, correlation

Compute correlation between $aX + bY$ and $cX + dY$, for real numbers $a, b, c, d$ and independent $N(0, 1)$ variables $X, Y$ .

I have the following:
$\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}$
$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$
\begin{align*}
\Cov(aX + bY, cX + dY)&= E\left[(aX + bY)(cX + dY)\right] - E(aX+bY)E(cX+dY)\\
&= E\left(acX^2 +(ad + bc)XY + bdY^2\right) - (aEX+bEY)(cEX+dEY)\\
&= acE\left(X^2\right) + (ad + bc)E(XY) + bdE(Y^2) \\&\phantom{=}- \left[ac(EX)^2 + (ad + bc)EXEY + bdE\left(Y^2\right)\right]\\
&=ac\Var X + bd\Var Y + (ad + bc)\left[E(XY) - EXEY\right]\\
&= ac + bd
\end{align*}
where the last step follows from the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent $N(0,1)$ variables. Then,
\begin{align*}
\rho(aX + bY, cX + dY) &= \frac{ac + bd}{\sqrt{\Var(aX + bY)\Var(cX + dY)}}\\
&= \frac{ac + bd}{\sqrt{(a^2\Var X + b^2\Var Y)(c^2\Var X + d^2\Var Y)}}\\
&= \frac{ac + bd}{\sqrt{(a^2+ b^2)(c^2+ d^2)}}\\
\end{align*}

Is there any way to simplify this last expression further? For example to remove the square root, etc.

Comment: The square root can be removed only if $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$. I don´t see other simplifications.